# Why does iabbrev end at second character, even after using 0 at the end of command chain?

Tags: cursor, abbreviations

This behaviour seems a bit strange (`^` is the cursor):

```
inoreabbrev @@t <esc>0

what@@t
what
 ^
```

But:

```
inoreabbrev @@t <esc>0h

what@@t
what
^
```

Why using `0` is not enough to put the cursor at the beginning of the line after abbreviation?

Comment: You typing `space` count, try `c-]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why using 0 is not enough to put the cursor at the beginning of the line after abbreviation?

When you press space, Vim expands `@@t` into `<esc>0`, then the space command is executed.  In insert mode, the space command inserts a space, but in normal mode it moves the cursor 1 character forward (see `:h <space>`).

To prevent the space from interfering, you can consume it with `getchar()`:

```
inorea <silent> @@t <esc>0@=<sid>eat_space()<cr>
fu s:eat_space() abort
    let c = nr2char(getchar(0))
    return c =~# '\s' ? '' : c
endfu
```

See `:helpgrep Eatchar`.

Comment: or use CTRL-] in insert mode (see, `:h i_CTRL-]`)